# Error: Transaction reverted: trying to deploy a contract whose code is too large using hardhat test but works fine using ganache

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, hardhat

I am trying to test the contracts that I have built and I know I am using a factory method to create liquidity pools and I know that their sizes didn't exceeded the maximum contract size otherwise there will be a warning. I tried to change my contracts making other branches just to experiment but calling new Contract to deploy a contract makes hardhat to throw

> Error: Transaction reverted: trying to deploy a contract whose code is
> too large

and I have built a deployer contract to deploy the child contracts in that way I can assure that there is no contract to exceed the limit

With any method and test that lead to the same error I tried to use ganache and yeah the test works perfectly fine but would it effect give the same error if I deploy it to the mainnet?